# Xserver doesn't want to start

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have a problem with `14.04`, my machine wouldn't come back as usual from stand-by to showing me the password prompt but it displayed some message that didn't contain much information on a shell screen instead. 
So, I power cycled my machine and on bootup, I didn't get to the X11 login screen but instead, it throws me to a shell login. I've tried to restart `sudo service lighdm start` manually but that just gets me a black screen with a cursor flashing in the top left corner. Now can can I get my X back? I don't know what happened, in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I see something like `Device(s) dtected, but none match those in the config file` - how can I get this adjusted for my two screens to match? My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 331.49  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-10)  Wed Feb 12 21:00:07 PST 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

$
```

I have two monitors connected, one is a `HP 2511x` and the other one is an `acer AL2216W`

**edit 1**

automatically created `xorg.conf` by `nvidia-xconfig`

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 331.38  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-15)  Wed Jan  8 19:53:14 PST 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[  2426.198] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[  2426.198] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2426.198] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  2426.198] Current Operating System: Linux regDesktopHome 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64
[  2426.198] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic root=UUID=b0488ebc-79a6-49dc-b86f-fd3d9b1d746a ro quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
[  2426.198] Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
[  2426.198] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  2426.198] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[  2426.198]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2426.198] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2426.198] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Dec  6 12:56:33 2014
[  2426.199] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  2426.199] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2426.199] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  2426.199] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  2426.199] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[  2426.199] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[  2426.199] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[  2426.199] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[  2426.199] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2426.199] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2426.199] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2426.199] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2426.199]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2426.199] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2426.199]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2426.199] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2426.199]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2426.199] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2426.199]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2426.199] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2426.200]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2426.200] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[  2426.200] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2426.200] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  2426.200] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  2426.200] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  2426.200] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fd6d26ead40
[  2426.200] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2426.200]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2426.200]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[  2426.200]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[  2426.200]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[  2426.200] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2426.201] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1040:1043:83c6 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0xe8000000/134217728, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension Present
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[  2426.201] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[  2426.201] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[  2426.201] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[  2426.201] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[  2426.201] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2426.201] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2426.213] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2426.213]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  2426.213]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[  2426.213] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  2426.213] Loading extension GLX
[  2426.213] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  2426.213] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[  2426.213] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[  2426.213] (II) Unloading nvidia
[  2426.213] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2426.213] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2426.214] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2426.214] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2426.214] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2426.214] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[  2426.214] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[  2426.214] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[  2426.214] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2426.214] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  2426.214] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[  2426.214] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[  2426.214] (II) Unloading nvidia
[  2426.214] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2426.214] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  2426.214] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[  2426.215] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2426.215]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.0.10
[  2426.215]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2426.215]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  2426.215] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2426.215] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module modesetting
[  2426.215] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2426.215] (II) Unloading modesetting
[  2426.215] (EE) Failed to load module "modesetting" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2426.215] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2426.215] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2426.215] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2426.215]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[  2426.215]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2426.215]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  2426.215] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2426.215] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2426.216] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2426.216]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[  2426.216]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2426.216]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  2426.216] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Nov 7 14:56:48 2013 +1000
[  2426.216] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  2426.216]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[  2426.216]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[  2426.216]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[  2426.216]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[  2426.216]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[  2426.216]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[  2426.216] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2426.216] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2426.216] (++) using VT number 7

[  2426.220] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[  2426.220] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[  2426.220] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[  2426.220] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[  2426.220] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[  2426.220] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2426.220] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2426.220] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2426.221] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2426.221]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  2426.221]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  2426.221] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[  2426.221] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  2426.221] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2426.221] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2426.222] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2426.222] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2426.222]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  2426.222]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  2426.222] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[  2426.222] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
[  2426.222] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  2426.222] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2426.222] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2426.222] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2426.222] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2426.222] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  2426.222] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[  2426.222] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2426.222] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  2426.222] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  2426.222] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  2426.222] (EE) 
[  2426.223] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
$
```

**edit 2**

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
[sudo] password for ron: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-331 is already the newest version.
```

So I did a `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-331` followed by a `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we indicated through the comments that the NVIDIA Drivers are not installed try to reinstall the nvidia drivers by following the the linked doc under section **Installation without X / from the console**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-331` did the trick. (Check Edit 2)

Comment: I did what yu said but no new `xorg.conf` got created: `$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does you X-Server still not start - even if there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf ? You may also try to rerun the nvidia-xconfig tool from commandline. For example `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Comment: no it. didn't start either without `xorg.con`, I executed `nvidia-xconfig` and it said it created a new `xorg.conf`. I then retried to `sude service lightdm start` but I still get nothing than the blinking cursor in the top left corner... also see **edit 1** above, please

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors ?

Comment: I also added `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to **edit 1** now. `syslog` and `messages` is empty

Comment: `[  2426.213] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)` indicates that the nvidia proprietary drivers are not installed. Have you upgraded ubuntu or installed updates ?

Comment: Yes, I have done installed all pending updates and I think the Xserver should also run without the proprietary Nvidia drivers, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try to reinstall nvidia drivers as described in the answer. I updated the answer to follow the policy to avoid long discussions in comments. Let me know if this works. If not lets move this discussion, let me know and I'll move this to a discussion chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19245/discussion-between-kofrezo-and-cerr).